# Using functions of an object you know will be created in Javascript and Angular (featuring Peerjs and Socket.io)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sockets, peerjs

I have the following code snippet

```
var peer = {};

var foo = function ($scope, socket) { // socket is a factory to wrap socket.io in angular
    socket.on('setUID', function (data) {
        peer = new Peer(data);
    });
};

var bar = function ($scope, socket) {
    peer.on('connect', function () { alert("blah"); }); // this line doesn't work
}

// foo and bar are both controllers in angular, which are attached to separate areas in the application
```

Essentially, what I am trying to do is create a new PeerJS peer using a server-generated ID which is transmitted using socket.io as soon as the client connects. As such, I know that the peer object will be created before the on listener is triggered. However, I don't think javascript knows that. How can I set it up so that I can use the future functions of the peer in my controllers?

EDIT: Here is what I have at the moment

```
app.factory('peer', function ($rootScope, socket) {
    var peer = {};

    socket.on('setUID', function (data) {
        peer = new Peer(data, {host: 'localhost', port: 9000, path: "/peer/"});
        console.log("Peer created");
        peer.on('open', function (id) { // these work fine
            console.log('My peer ID is: ' + id);
        });

        peer.on('connection', function (conn) {
            conn.on('open', function () {
                conn.on('data', function (data) {
                    console.log("Received: " + data);
                });
            });
        });
    });

    return {
        getPeer: function () {
            return peer;
        }
    };
});


var bar = function ($scope, socket, peer) {
    var p = peer.getPeer();
    p.on("connection", console.log("hello")); // works once, then says p.on is not a function
}
```

Comment: Still have same timing problem with `peer.getPeer()` it may or may not return an instantiated `Peer` depending on when the `socket.on("setUID",...)` happens

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be attaching the event listeners after the `Peer` is created like this:

```
var peer = {};

var foo = function ($scope, socket) { // socket is a factory to wrap socket.io in angular
    socket.on('setUID', function (data) {
        peer = new Peer(data);
        peer.on("connect", function () { alert("Hi!"); });
    });
};
```

The `peer` object in your `bar` (where your example attaches the listener) doesn't need to be there, and as you found, it doesn't work like this. It's not clear what need that `bar` has with `peer` from your example, but if you needed to share an object with multiple controllers you should wrap the object in a service that is injected into each controller:

```
var PeerService = function ($q, socket) {
  var defered = $q.defer();
  var peer;

  socket.on("setUID", function (data) {
    peer = new Peer(data);
    deferred.resolve(p);
  });

  return {
    connected: function (callback) {
      $q.success(function () {
        callback(peer);
      });
    }
  }
};

var bar = function ($scope, PeerService) {
  $scope.data = [];

  PeerService.connected(function (peer) {
    peer.on("data", function (data) {
      $scope.data.push(data);
    })
  });
}
```

This `PeerService` will accept the callback and the callback will not be called until it can provide a `peer` object. This pattern handles the controller calling `PeerService.connected()` before there is a `peer` (i.e. it is deferred) as well as the case where the controller is instantiated after the `peer` (i.e. it is immediately invoked with peer)

Comment: Sorry, I should have mentioned that foo is a controller for one section, whereas bar is a controller for another. I'll edit the original question to reflect that.

Other than that, if I use the proposed PeerService idea, I assume I will be able to create the peer object using the parameters and access it and its functions from another controller, correct?

Comment: Yes, the example isn't clear as to the role `bar` and the `peer` play (because we like to simplify our examples) but the comment about wrapping in a service applies. You'll still have to manage the fact that your controllers etc come into play at some time before or possibly after the `Peer` has been instantiated, and a service is the Angular way to approach this.

Comment: Sorry for the triple post, but I guess in the end, it doesn't really matter where the event listeners are, does it? In that case, I can just place them in the service, correct?

Comment: In this case the service seems to be a good place to handle connection events etc... the `data` events could be handled by the code that wants to listen to them e.g. another controller.